# ReactJS Calling method with onClick doesn't work fully

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, methods, visualization

so i'm making a sorting visualization in ReactJS.
I have a method called "bubbleSort" that will follow bubble sort algorithm to sort array.
I have an array generated and visualized on the screen called "array".
Now when i use

```
<button onClick={bubbleSort(array)}>Click here to sort</button>
```

It will Sort the array and change the visualized array automatically everytime the page loads. It's not what i want, i want it to sort the array and change the visualization when i click the button.
So i made another method like this

```
function doSort() {
   bubbleSort(array);
   console.log(array);
   }
```

and call the button like this `<button onClick={doSort}>Click here to sort</button>`, it will sort the array, but the visualized array on the screen stay the same (random) and is not display correctly (sorted). I'm stuck and don't know what to do. Thank you very much for your time to help me.

Comment: Please could you add the output of your console.log statement

Comment: What does `bubbleSort` do? What is `array`?

Comment: @PaulMichaels the output of the console.log is the sorted array. For example i have an array like [5, 4, 6, 2, 1]. The console.log will be [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: @Aron bubbleSort is a function that will sort an array from random to least to biggest. an Array is a random array like [5, 4, 6, 2, 1] that is visualized on the screen as colored bars

Comment: Is `array` a state variable? A prop? Does `bubbleSort` use a state setter to update the state or does it just try to mutate the array in place?

Comment: @Aron `array` is a hook. `const [array, setArray] = useState([])`. And `bubbleSort` doesn't use a state setter. Let me try to add it

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should call the function using the pattern below.

```
<button onClick={() => bubbleSort(array)}>Click here to sort</button>
```

Comment: thank you i tried that but it didn't work

Comment: What if you try it like this `<button onClick={() => bubbleSort([2,1,3])}>Click here to sort</button>`